# scale_fill_gradientn in R maps

Tags: r, colors, maps

I am trying to follow the tutorial in http://aasa.ut.ee/Rspatial/05_session.html
and I am having difficulties to reproduce the code with scale_fill_gradientn with my data.

My data is a df with 3 columns: lon, lat and Xobs , the latter with integers as they represent numbers of observations of certain element. My code is:

```
ggplot()+
geom_point(data = sites12i, aes(x = lon, y=lat, colour = X0bs))+
scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10)) +
labs(title = "sites k=1,2")+
coord_fixed()
```

however I get all points with the same color.
what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Have you checked that `X0bs` is a numeric vector and that it has more than one value?

Comment: it looks like this: 'data.frame': 126 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ lon : num  16.5 16.9 17 17.1 17.1 ...
 $ lat : num  -28.6 -29.2 -28.4 -29.7 -29 ...
 $ X0bs: int  3 2 7 1 3 2 3 5 1 17 ...

Comment: so it's a collection of integers

Comment: I used identical code to yours (but with slightly different values, though also integer class for the column mapped to color) and I get the colors as intended, with R 4.0.0 and ggplot2 3.3.0

Comment: I used ggplot 3.3.0 and R 4.0.2patched. I will replicate with R 4.0.0 and will get back

Comment: the problem persists. Is it possible that is being interfered by another loaded program ?

Comment: I started again, loaded only ggplot2, and still get the same result using either R4.0.0 or 4.0.2patched

Comment: hi Allan, I tried converting the data from int to num, different versions of R and ggplot and cannot get my head around it. Can you send me the test data and the code you wrote and I try that on my side please ? greatly appreciated.